# Pipeline groovy script denies special character

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube, jenkins-groovy

I have this script which generates the information about SonarQube branches and their lines of codes. Everything went smooth until I discovered that there is one branch in one SonarQube project that contains "$" on it's branch name (`branch-$branch`). After iterating over the list of branches on that specific SonarQube project, it rejects that branch to display it's output.

How can I allow the usage of "$" in my script?

Here is my script:

```
stage('Extract Output') {
        steps {
            script {
                 
                // Sonar branches API Endpoint
                String branches_url = base_url+"/api/project_branches/list"
                
                String sonar_branches = sh(script: 'curl -s -u user:pswd -X GET -F "project=sonar.project" '+branches_url, returnStdout: true).trim()
                def jsonSonarBranches = readJSON text: sonar_branches

                p_branches = jsonSonarBranches.branches
                branch_name = p_branches.name
                branch_LAD = p_branches.analysisDate

                echo "${branch_name}"
                echo "------------------"

                // LOC API Endpoint
                String measures_url = base_url+"/api/measures/component"
                
                int index = 0
                for(String branch: branch_name){
                    brnch_lad = branch_LAD.get(index)

                    String project_measures = sh(script: 'curl -s -u usr:paswd -X GET -F "component=sonar.project" -F "metricKeys=ncloc" -F "branch='+branch+'" '+measures_url, returnStdout: true).trim()
                    def jsonProjectMeasures = readJSON text: project_measures
                    
                    // components json: value = loc
                    proj_component = jsonProjectMeasures.component.measures
                    p_measures = proj_component.value

                    if(brnch_lad == null){
                        brnch_lad = 'N/A'
                        p_measures = 'N/A'
                        echo "PROJECT_KEY:sonar.project BRANCH:${branch} LAD:${brnch_lad} LOC:${p_measures}"
                    } 
                    else if(p_measures.isEmpty()) {
                        p_measures = 'N/A'
                        echo "PROJECT_KEY:sonar.project BRANCH:${branch} LAD:${brnch_lad} LOC:${p_measures}"  
                    }
                    else if(p_measures == null){
                        p_measures = 'N/A'
                        echo "PROJECT_KEY:sonar.project BRANCH:${branch} LAD:${brnch_lad} LOC:${p_measures}"
                    }
                    else {
                        int index_measures = 0
                        p_loc = p_measures.get(index_measures)
                        echo "PROJECT_KEY:sonar.project BRANCH:${branch} LAD:${brnch_lad} LOC:${p_loc}"
                    
                        index_measures++
                    }

                    index++
                }
                echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
            }
        }
    }
```

So upon echoing "${branch_name}", the result was:

```
[branch-123, branch-master, branch-origin/pr, branch-$branch]
```

It normally displays the branches on my logs, but when I perform the for loop on `String branch: branch_name` it denies the branch "**branch-$branch**" but for other branches they display smoothly.

Output of **branch-$branch**:

```
+ curl -s -u **** -X GET -F component=sonar.project -F metricKeys=ncloc -F branch=branch- https://sonarqube.com/api/measures/component
```

PS.
I tried to add `branch_name = p_branches.name.toString()` but no luck &
I can't change the branch name as this is a project inside our org.

Comment: This is because the Groovy interpreter handles the characters correctly, but the shell interpreter in your `sh` step method is attempting to resolve and interpolate the branch as a variable in the `curl` command. You could perhaps use https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/ to circumvent this.

Comment: Hi @Matthew Schuchard , I see, that's why it keeps on rejecting the special character. Maybe I'll keep in touch as soon as I have applied this plugin on my issue. Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it and it helps a lot :)